# Retrofit 1.9 with OkHttp 2.2 and interceptors

Tags: android, retrofit, square, okhttp

I thought that these recent versions were supposed to be compatible. There is this tweet;
https://twitter.com/JakeWharton/status/553066921675857922 and the changelog of Retrofit 1.9 mentions it too.

However when I try this:

```
        OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        httpClient.interceptors().add(new TokenExpiredInterceptor());

        mRestAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(API_ENDPOINT)
                .setClient(httpClient)
                .setLogLevel(BuildConfig.DEBUG ?
                        RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL :
                        RestAdapter.LogLevel.NONE)
                .setRequestInterceptor(new AuthorizationInterceptor())
                .build();
```

It still doesn't work. The setClient method complains about an incompatible Client object;

```
Error:(29, 21) error: no suitable method found for setClient(OkHttpClient)
method Builder.setClient(Client) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; OkHttpClient cannot be converted to Client)
method Builder.setClient(Provider) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; OkHttpClient cannot be converted to Provider)
```

What am I missing? I also see OkHttpClient does not implement the Client interface.

I am using this approach for now; https://medium.com/@nullthemall/execute-retrofit-requests-directly-on-okhttp-2-2-7e919d87b64e

Did I misinterpret the changelog? Maye Retrofit 1.9 can uses OkHttpClient 2.2 when it's in the classpath but the interface isn't adapted yet?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are passing `OkHttpClient` to the `RestAdapter.Builder` which accepts `Client` implementations. `OkHttpClient`, solely, is not related to Retrofit if not used in `Client` implementations.

You should pass `OkHttpClient` to `OkClient` instance that implements `Client`

`.setClient(new OkClient(httpClient))`

```
OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
httpClient.interceptors().add(new TokenExpiredInterceptor());

mRestAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint(API_ENDPOINT)
        .setClient(new OkClient(httpClient))
        .setLogLevel(BuildConfig.DEBUG ?
                RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL :
                RestAdapter.LogLevel.NONE)
        .setRequestInterceptor(new AuthorizationInterceptor())
        .build();
```

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I missed that :p

Comment: @UsmanAfzal This is unrelated to the question, you should search if someone has this issue before or ask your own question.